# CFMail attachment filename broken in ColdFusion 2016 on Windows server

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I'm moving a site from CF10 on Linux to CF2016 on Windows, and have run into an issue with file attachments with cfmail.

I'm attaching the file in cfmail with;

```
<cfmailparam file="#FileName#">
```

and have also tried variations with and without disposition and type like:

```
<cfmailparam file="#FileName#" disposition="attachment; 
         filename=""#FileName#""" 
         type="#ContentType#/#ContentSubType#">
```

But no matter what, on CF2016 on Windows, my attachments names in Outlook come through as `ATT00160.dat` (without type set) or `ATT00169.xlsx` (with type set)

It seems filenames over a certain length cause the issue. A filename of 64 characters will break it, but a smaller filename, of say 49 characters, won't.

Viewing the message source in Outlook, from the cfmail sent from Windows, I see the value below.  Notice under `content-type` the name has been split?

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name*0=BLAH_BLAH1_Ownership_Database_Issue_2018-01_In_Development2.; 
    name*1=xlsx
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename*0=BLAH_BLAH1_Ownership_Database_Is;
 filename*1=sue_2018-01_In_Development2.xlsx
```

The same attachment sent with cfmail, from Linux, gives me:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name=BLAH_BLAH1_Ownership_Database_Issue_2018-01_In_Development2.xlsx
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename*0=BLAH_BLAH1_Ownership_Database_Is;
 filename*1=sue_2018-01_In_Development2.xlsx
```

Note the `content-type` name has not been split.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try setting `decode` attribute as `false` or `filename`( Introduced in 2016 ) attribute?

Comment: thanks @Beginner - i tried decode="false" and filename="#filename#" individually and together - no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I finally sorted it. You need to manually put the file name in the type:

```
<cfmailparam file="#FileName#" 
      type="#ContentType#/#ContentSubType#;name=""#FileName#""">
```

I've never needed to do that previously. I don't know if this is a Windows server, CF2016 or SmarterMail (our mail server) thing, but if you run into the same issue, the above worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might also see my report to Adobe Bug tracker.  I have had trouble with long file name attachments ever since Coldfusion switched to the newer Javamail.

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4199784